# Use Boost Preprocessor to Parse sequence of elements

Tags: c++, boost, boost-preprocessor

I have a macro defined which is

```
#define TYPES (height,int,10)(width,int,20)
```

How to expand this macro using Boost Preprocessor something like this?

```
int height = 10;
int width = 20;
```

at most i am able to get is **height,int,10** and **width,int,20** as string but can't parse individual element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SEQ_TO_SEQ` to turn `TYPES` into `((height,int,10))((width,int,20))` before processing, so that `BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH` doesn't choke on it:

```
#define MAKE_ONE_VARIABLE(r, data, elem) \
    BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(1, elem) BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(0, elem) = BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, elem);

#define MAKE_VARIABLES(seq) \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(MAKE_ONE_VARIABLE, ~, BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SEQ_TO_SEQ(seq))
```

Usage:

```
#define TYPES (height,int,10)(width,int,20)

int main() {
    MAKE_VARIABLES(TYPES)
}
```

Is preprocessed into:

```
int main() {
    int height = 10; int width = 20;
}
```

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db6246c395680fe2)

Comment: Shouldn't boost already have something like that GLK_PP_SEQ_DOUBLE_PARENS?

Comment: @Phantom not that I know of, unfortunately.

Comment: @Quentin, check out BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SEQ_TO_SEQ.
(https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/variadic_seq_to_seq.html)

Comment: @Quentin, if there are commas between `(height, int, 10)` and `(width, int, 20)` , Can you explain what to do to parse sequence?

Comment: @JafarGh this can be done by replacing `BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SEQ_TO_SEQ` with `BOOST_PP_TUPLE_TO_SEQ`, give or take a few parentheses: [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b34717ecbf6ba634).